# django 2 crud operations without database with external api

Tags: python, django, rest, api, django-models

I have an external third-party API client for retrieving and storing song names and I need to interface it with Django 2 and permit the user through Django forms to insert and update songs **without using any database backend** but only the API.

I'm struggling as most documentation on Django assumes a database backend and even examples on consuming an external API assume I want to store fetched data from a REST API to the database.

The **external API is not even REST**, I simply have a client.py module with all methods I need to do CRUD operations on a remote service storing song info.

I looked into creating a Django 2 custom model manager but it seems this is used as something above an existing database and not an external API.
Django 2 serializers permit to serialize and deserialize data in between an API and a database.

What I'm missing is the way to create a custom model abstracting the API and permitting me to use it as if it were a database so that I can go on and follow any Django forms tutorial after having abstracted the model layer.

**NOTE:** similar problem asked [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/django/comments/33po56/django_app_that_communicates_with_existing_rest/), answer was: "*Django is a database-centric back-end framework, skip Django and use Angular*" is that so hard for Django?

Currently I hacked something like the SSCE example below:

### urls.py :

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', viewSong, name='home'),
    url(r'^create/$', SongCreate.as_view(), name='create'),
    url(r'^update/(?P<song_id>[0-9\.a-z]+)/$', SongUpdate.as_view(), name='update'),
]
```

### templates/form.html :

```
<form role="form" action="/create/" method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="song-id">Song Id</label>
                    <input type="text" id="song-id" name="song-id">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="song-name">Song Name</label>
                    <input type="text" id="song-name" name="song-name">
                </div>
</form>
```

### views.py :

```
class SongCreate(CreateView):
    template_name = 'form.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = SongForm()
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

    def post(self, request):
        form = SongForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect("/")
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})


class SongUpdate(UpdateView):
    template_name = 'form.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        song_id = kwargs["song_id"]
        obj = SongModel.load(song_id)
        form = SongForm(obj)
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

### forms.py :

```
class SongForm(forms.Form):
    song_id = forms.CharField(label='song_id', max_length=30)
    song_name = forms.CharField(label='song_name', max_length=100)

    def save(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data
        songModel = SongModel(song_id=data['song_id'],
                              song_name=data['song_name'])
        songModel.save()
```

### models.py :

```
from django.db import models
from woozy.song_client import SongClient

username = 'woozyuser'
password = 'userpass'
base_url = 'http://localhost:8080'

class SongModel(models.Model):
    song_id = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    song_name = models.CharField(max_length=80)

    def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None,
             update_fields=None):
        songClient = SongClient()
        songClient.connect(base_url, username, password)
        songClient.create_song(self.song_id,
                               self.song_name)
        return

    @classmethod
    def load(cls, song_id):
        song_model = cls(song_id=song_id)
        songClient = SongClient()
        songClient.connect(base_url, username, password)
        song = songClient.get_song(song_id)
        return song
```

the above seems a little convoluted to me so I guess I'm not respecting the various layers and architecture that Django supports.